# Can you take 2 gems of the same kind for 2-3 players?

Tags: splendor

It says in the rule book that you can only take 2 gems of the same kind only if there'll be at least 4 chips left after you take the 2. Since you only have 4 chips for two players and 5 chips for three players, is the ability to take 2 gems of the same kind reserved for four players only?

Comment: Re "*if there'll be at least 4 chips left after you take the 2*", No, it says if there *are* at least 4 chips left *when* you take 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are reading the rules incorrectly, they says when there are 4 chips at the start of your turn not after you take them. The rules don't care how many gems are in a stack after you have taken them just beforehand.

[Rules](https://armadagames.com/splendor/)

> Collect Gem Chips – Either:Take 1 Gem from each of 3 different stacks (not gold)
>   1: Take 2 Gems from one stack, as long as there are 4 or more chips in that stack

In a 4 player game there can be 3 chips missing at the start of your turn, 3 player 1 chip missing and 2 player no chips missing.

Testing on the iOs version of the game lets me draw two chips of the same color from a stack when there is exactly 4 chips on it in a two player game.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I just misunderstood the rules, since that rule was kind of ambiguously worded in the English version. So, for example, if 2 players were playing and the first player takes 2 diamonds from the original 4, the second player wouldn't be able to do the same feat and take the remaining 2 diamonds left. Is that correct?

Comment: @FenderOrcajo yep when reading the rules online (don't have my copy with me) it is a bit confusing how they did that section with two lines.

Comment: @FenderOrcajo I tested on the iOs version and it let me draw two chips from a stack in a 2 player game when there was 4 chips on the stack.